# Did P/Invoke environment change in .NET 4.0?

Tags: delphi, .net-4.0, pinvoke

I've started upgrading a .NET 2.0 WinForms application to .NET 4.0.  Well, OK, the upgrade process was just a matter of switching platform target, but making it actually work.  I assumed that's all there would be to it.

But it seems that something drastically changed in .NET 4.0 regarding interop.  Using DllImport(), the application embeds a couple Delphi dlls.  When the application targets .NET 2.0, everything works normally.  But when I changed it to target .NET 4.0, stuff starts going haywire, like something is corrupting memory.

For example, it replaces single digits with "0" in strange places.  Data passed in an IStream gets 8 characters replaced with (Hex) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80, but only about 70% of the time.  Two consecutive calls to retrieve the same value return different results (retrieving a value from a cache in memory, succeeds the first time, fails the second time).  Strings being sent to a log are showing up truncated.

I've tried lots of stuff trying to make calling conventions more explicit, none of it has any effect.  All strings are handled as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] on the .NET side and PWChar on the Delphi side.

What changed in .NET 4.0 that would break P/Invoke like this?

----------------------------Edit-------------------------------------

Here's the simplest example.  It generates a PDF which sometimes works correctly, but more frequently ends up corrupt (and works correctly in .NET 2.0):

```
[DllImport(DLLName)]
public static extern void SetDBParameters(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Server,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Database,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string User,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Password,
    short IntegratedSecurity);

procedure SetDBParameters(Server, Database, User, Password: PWChar;
    IntegratedSecurity: WordBool); stdcall;


[DllImport(DLLName)]
public static extern short GeneratePDF(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Param1,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Param2,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Param3,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Param4,
    out IStream PDFData);

function GeneratePDF(Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4: PWChar;
    out PDFData: IStream): WordBool; stdcall;

private byte[] ReadIStream(IStream Stream)
{
    if (Stream == null)
        return null;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG streamstats;
    Stream.Stat(out streamstats, 0);
    Stream.Seek(0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (streamstats.cbSize <= 0)
        return null;
    byte[] result = new byte[streamstats.cbSize];
    Stream.Read(result, (int)streamstats.cbSize, IntPtr.Zero);
    return result;
}
```

WordBool and short were originally boolean (Delphi) and bool (C#), I changed them to be more explicit, just in case.

----------------------------Edit-------------------------------------

The stuff I wrote earlier about WinForms appears to have turned out to be not completely relevant, I've recreated one of the issues without any UI.  The following program generates 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 under 2.0/3.5, but 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 under 4.0.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestNet4interop
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("TestSimpleLibrary.dll", PreserveSig=true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void AddToList(long value);

        [DllImport("TestSimpleLibrary.dll", PreserveSig=true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int GetFromList(long value);

        static void Main()
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                AddToList(i);
                Console.WriteLine(GetFromList(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Delphi side (compiled with Delphi 2007):

```
library TestSimpleLibrary;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

var
   List: TStringList;

procedure AddToList(value: int64); stdcall;
begin
   List.Add(IntToStr(value));
end;

function GetFromList(value: int64): integer; stdcall;
begin
   result := List.IndexOf(IntToStr(value));
end;

exports
   AddToList,
   GetFromList;

begin
   List := TStringList.Create;
end.
```

Comment: Can you show us the PInvoke signature?

Comment: This post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/922fa431-5426-48c6-8949-538dfbb2f266 suggests that marshalling did change in 4.0, but doesn't provide a complete list of what did change.

Comment: Perhaps interesting to know: [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) does **not** fix the issue, we've just tried it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger.  It seems to be clobbering memory that doesn't belong to it.  All of the problems I've observed (all of which can be reproduced reliably) disappear completely if I run the application directly, instead of through Visual Studio 2010.

The bug is actually in the Managed Debug Assistant.  If you turn it off completely (set HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\MDA = "0"), the problem goes away.  But of course you lose some debugging capability by doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Appears that this is a problem with the Calling Convention property in the DllImport attribute.  Should be Cdecl not the default StdCall.  I had this problem when migrating from 2.0 to 4.0 and running in VS2010.  See article here.  http://codenition.blogspot.com/2010/05/pinvokestackimbalance-in-net-40i-beg.html

Comment: The problem you describe is different.  When I tested the sample code above with Cdecl instead of StdCall, I got stack imbalance exceptions.  But with both sides declared StdCall, it doesn't imbalance the stack, it just corrupts the Delphi internals.  In your case it was the MDA that helped track down a legitimate issue, in the Delphi case, the MDA actually causes the issue.

Comment: But if someone is just looking at the title of my original question, your answer here is quite relevant, P/Invoke did change in 4.0.  It just didn't have anything to do with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is a one byte type on Delphi. So changing them must be with a one byte type

Comment: I wasn't sure what size either side assumes, so I changed it to WordBool and short (both 16 bits) everywhere it appeared.  But that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar problem with a Delphi dll:
[social_msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/clr/thread/3a13866b-0032-4178-ab7d-3b0958a43e23) 
I have noticed that my library compiled with FreePascal (instead of Delphi) works even within VS2010 without any problems. Therefore I don't know if Delphi, the `.NET4` debugger or the combination is the reason for the trouble.

There is some evidence that memory allocated during dll start-up (e.g. in the initialization section) is affected by the memory corruption.

Comment: I've seen problems distinctly disconnected from startup... unless it's somehow corrupting the Delphi memory manager to the point it's re-allocating the same memory for different things.  It seems to behave in a deterministic but unpredictable manner.